# setup settings send to its parent class in ruby

Tags: ruby, class

how can i write this (child) class like so:

```
class child < parent
  create_columns :name, :address
end

so that:

class parent
# Can access the create_columns set by the child class?
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using the inherited hook method in Ruby, so you can track all the children.

```
class Parent
 self.inherited(base)
    self.children << base
  end
end

class Child < Parent
def initialize
  @@instances << self
end

def self.instances
  @@instances
end
```

Now you can do things like Parent.children.each { |child| child.instances.collect(:&name) }. If name is accessable :-)

Hope that helps!

Comment: would that allow me to do something as above how my child class declares create_columns?

Comment: Well, I assume create_columns create readable fields, so yeah, you can access them via Parent.children.each(&:instances). As in, in this setting a Parent can have multiple children, and each child can have multiple instances.